# How to check if Widget has mounted in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

So in my app, I want to make an Ajax request as soon as the widget is mounted, not in `initState()`. Similar to `ComponentWillMount()` in **react**

Comment: [This](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/mounted.html) and [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/6246) might help.

Answer (score 47):

if the Widget has not [mounted](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/mounted.html) then return. Do it before the [setState](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html) method

```
if (!mounted) return;
setState(() {});
```

or

```
if (mounted) {
   //Do something
};
setState(() {});
```

Comment: "It is an error to call setState unless mounted is true."
- official docs .. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/mounted.html

Answer (score 20):

If you want to execute some code **as soon as the widget loaded** , you could simply put this code in the `initstate` like the following ;

```
 void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => yourFunction(context));   
 }
```

In this way , the `yourFunction` will be exectued as soon as the first frame of the widget loaded on the screen.

Comment: this should be marked an answer

Answer (score 8):

I don't think it's currently possible.

Here's the `mounted` property: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart#L974

```
bool get mounted => _element != null;
```

And here's when `_element` is set: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart#L3816

```
_state._element = this
```

And I don't see any hook around this code that would inform us.

Why not use `initState` anyway? It's probably what you want. Here's the comment above the `mounted` property: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart#L967

```
  /// After creating a [State] object and before calling [initState], the
  /// framework "mounts" the [State] object by associating it with a
  /// [BuildContext]. The [State] object remains mounted until the framework
```

Answer (score 8):

Simply do this as follows.

```
if (this.mounted) {
        setState(() {
         //Your code
        });
}
```

Answer (score 6):

With the latest update, **Flutter 3.7**, you can directly check whether the widget is mounted using the **context**. Here's an example use:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return OutlinedButton(
      onPressed: () async {
        await Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
        if (context.mounted) {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
        }
      },
      child: const Text('Delayed pop'),
    );
  }
```

For details, refer to [this page](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext/mounted.html).

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer comes a little bit late but...

Inside your method, you should have something like this:

```
if(mounted){
   setState(() {});
 }
```

This would help, to rebuild the UI only if something changes.
I use this myself inside a method, where I fill my list with users from firestore.

The mounted property helps to avoid the error, when you trying to call setState before build.

Comment: you don't need a boolean operator to check a boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

For setState, you can override it with mounted check, so you don't need to use the check all the time.

```
  @override
  void setState(fn) {
    if (mounted) {
      super.setState(fn);
    }
  }
```